# Yii Making straight urls for accessing user pages

Tags: php, yii, crud

Now in my Yii application I have th following userpage access url.

```
mysite/users/view?username=123
```

which loads view file of users controller.

What I want to do is to simplify URL to this

```
mysite/users/123
```

And entering this I want to access the same page.

Is that possible ?
For now my View action of UsersController is here :

```
public function actionView($username){
    $model = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        "username" => $username
    ));
    if($model){
        $this->render("view", array(
            "model" => $model
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the urlManager component within the config/main.php

```
'user/<username:\d+>' => 'user/view' // will need to change \d+ if not working with numbers only.
```

That will change the url structure. What did you mean about entering?

Comment: No. I don't want to change URL. I want to change the way system works. I want the system to work without that "view" words.
So If I enter mysite/users/123 I want the site to load some page

Comment: Your question says you want to simplify the URL. if you want a url of mysite/users/123 you need to configure the url manager. This removes the "view?username=123" from the url, but it still tells Yii to call the view controller method

Comment: That works, but problem is that when I try to go back using breadcrumbs link 'mysite/users/index' page goes on reload at stays white. nothing loading.

Comment: Edit the bread crumb part of the view file so it goes to where you need it to go

Comment: But that means that default action links will not work, and I'll have to edit them manually all over the place in my code :)
I mean controller/index. Why index fails after this modification you offered ?

Comment: It shouldn't fail. Make sure that the method exists and that it renders something. Try something really simple like adding echo 'hello'; inside the method and see if that is displayed. Does the page error at all?

Comment: Update your question to show the index method of the controller and i'll update the Answer

Comment: No need, probably I had some typos. Question is solved, everything is working. By the way I must write one more rule to get read of the url  myssite/users/index, so It will start to look like mysite/users ?

Comment: Yes `'users' => 'users/index'`.